# click event firing multiple times in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I am firing click event inside the loop.it fires multiple times .
How can i stop firing multiple time.

My code:-

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

var i;
for(i=0;i<myArray.length;i++){
 $(".Mydiv").click(function(){

alert(myArray[i]);

});
}
```

just example code.

Actually, I am updating every second  Mydiv attr id using jQuery attr to get current user.
so when i click mydiv i should only get the current user id. but i fires all.

Thanks

Comment: how does modified div id look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you well, this is the solution:

```
  var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

  var i = 0;
  $(".Mydiv").click(function(){
     alert(myArray[i]);
     if(i < myArray.length-1) i++;
  });
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: +1: is it not better to change `if(i < myArray.length-1) i++;` to `i = (i < myArray.length-1) ? i++ : 0` so that may may cycle the result

Comment: @naveen yes, but in gowri's original code he didn't cycle. However, for cycling I'd do `i = (i+1)%length`. Anyway thanks for that good advice.

Comment: wow. so simple. i have never tht of using modulus before. thanks

Comment: @Edger : I am updating mydiv attr id using recursive function.

Comment: @Naveen You're welcome, thanks to you :) @gowri Please paste the code of that recursive function

Answer (score 0):

You cannot fire events in a loop using `.click()` it is binding a handler to an event for the element or elements found for the selector. To trigger a click you use `.trigger()`

But in order to access the attribute of a clicked element what you need is this:

```
 $(".Mydiv").click(function(){

alert($(this).attr('id'));

});
```

While you are binding to all elements in the class, the $(this) means you are only acting on the element that was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

In original code ,it bind click event myArray.length times,you just need to bind once.

so you can just simply do like this:

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var i = 0;
 $(".Mydiv").click(function(){
    alert(myArray[i]);
   //here change the i
    i = (i+1)%length ;
 });
```